# eLearning: Courses on Usability, UI, UX, or XD?

Tags: accessibility, mobile, tools

Considering User Experience Stack Exchange is in itself an educational tool, creating infomation hubs geared to different personas and users is no longer a tedious task. What are the applications, resources and communities we could use? Surely some Universities provide distant learning courses?

Answer (score 11):

- Carnegie Mellon's Open Learning Initiative offers [free distance/online courses](http://oli.web.cmu.edu/openlearning/forstudents/freecourses), some of which (Visual Communication Design, statistics, etc) are applicable to the ux field.
- The [Learning IA](http://iainstitute.org/en/learn/) section of the IAI's site is also rich in resources on this topic.
- Feb 16/10 update: Recently also came across the [AMA's Interactive Webcasts](http://www.marketingpower.com/_layouts/Reference/Webcast.aspx?page=2&topic=) which have some topics you may find potentially relevant, including some related to Customer Based Measurement, Incentives Online Customer Feedback Best Practices, Search Marketing, Engaging Users
- July 16th update: Some of these may be relevant as well: 
  [University and Cyberspace conference videos online](http://www.experientia.com/blog/university-and-cyberspace-conference-videos-online/)

Answer (score 10):

A free online course in [Web Usability](http://slisweb.sjsu.edu/classes/coursedesc.htm#LIBR251) is available from the San Jose State University's School of Library and Information Science. You can get the course on iTunes U through the iTunes Music Store, but it's also on YouTube (search for LIBR-251) and the [School's website](http://slisweb.sjsu.edu/).

I'm sure there are many similar courses, but this is just one I found recently.

Answer (score 6):

The Open University in the UK has at least one course in [Interaction Design](http://www3.open.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/course/m364.htm). While I've not studied with them, a friend of mine studied the above module last year and really found it useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the information design program through onlinelearning.com. I've taken two courses thus far and am very pleasantly surprised at the depth of knowledge of the instructor (Hans Bergman) and the knowledge I've gained. The price is reasonable, too, for working stiffs such as this old woman.

Comment: Kate, can you provide the url for the information design program-had a quick look at the site and didn't see the program listed. Thanks!

Comment: Nathalie... I'm not sure if you found the answer you're looking for, but it appears this is the link you need: http://www.online-learning.com/php_bin/course_overview.php

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the HCI Bibliography site's Education section: http://hcibib.org/education/,

Answer (score 1):

[MIT publishes a bunch of courses](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/) - both lectures, assignments, student projects, etc.  It's great to see how the conceptual tutoring later led to the assignments and then the projects, etc.

There are a wide variety of topics to choose from.  I must have downloaded about 25 or so modules the other day.

Don't also forget to go through the reading list.  They have links to some white papers that are super interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The following site contain information about UX Threads, Usability, User Experiences and a lot of other courses.

[Usability Training and Certification Overview](http://www.humanfactors.com/training/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIE Virtual Seminars](http://www.uie.com/events/virtual_seminars/). I've watched a couple of them and found them to be pretty helpful.